# Learning Materials

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, extensions, development

Can someone please point me at self-paced learning materials? There doesn't seem to be a whole lot out there for learning to develop extensions (both front end and admin panel), etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked a couple of times. Here are some on-site references:

[What interesting modules should I develop for Magento for learning?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/398/what-interesting-modules-should-i-develop-for-magento-for-learning)

[Learning Magento Plugin Development](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/learning-magento-plugin-development/4700#4700)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do in an extension, making the basics of an extension is easy and in fact can be generated using a link below. But in the end you will need to know things like PHP Mysql and HTML and CSS in order to make the extension actually do anything.

But here is some material on packaging Magento Extensions which should be the start in my opinion.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/

Those three PDFs are important, especially if you want to submit your extension to Magento connect.

You can create the "shell" of an extension using this site here:
http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

This is good to generate some stuff and see what it looks like, how it works etc. And then from there you are pretty much programming in other languages while talking to Magento.